# @classmethod for constructor overloading

Tags: python, python-3.x, constructor, class-method

I usually use `isinstance` for constructor overloading, but people also suggests `@classmethod` for the same. But to my knowledge `@classmethod` shares the variable.

Below is a simple class

```
class abc:
    def __init__(self, a=0):
        self.a = a    

    @classmethod
    def from_const(cls, b=30):
        cls.b = b
        return cls(10)

    def printme(self):
        print(self.a,self.b)
```

Now, lets make three objects

```
a1 = abc(a=100)
a2 = abc.from_const(b=31)
a3 = abc.from_const(b=41)
a4 = abc().from_const(b=51)
a5 = abc().from_const(b=61)


a1.printme()
a2.printme()
a3.printme()
a4.printme()
a5.printme()
```

The output:

```
100 61
10 61
10 61
10 61
10 61
```

Now I have two questions,

- Is it possible to make @classmethod not share class variables ?
- How to properly use @classmethod for constructor overloading ?

Comment: What is `b` even *for*, here? You're setting it on the class, `cls`, so it shouldn't be surprising that it's shared, but why are you setting it at all? Did you mean to do `return cls(b)` instead? Or set it on instances via `__init__`, and `return cls(10, b)` if it shouldn't be shared.

Comment: If you want to assign b attribute to each instance using `from_const`, maybe you want to init the instance, then assign b to it. Here's the idea : `@classmethod
    def from_const(cls, b=30):
        instance = cls(10)
        instance.b = b
        return instance`

Comment: Why do instances created by `from_const` have a `b` attribute, but instances created by `__init__` don't? That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: The code above is not a complete example, but to only show my doubt. I should have put it more clearly, but all I wanted to set two variables from different constructors

Comment: @madjaoue: I guess, i made this silly mistake of directly assigning it to class, you code was helpful. Thank you so much man!

Comment: As @Aran-Fey points out, though, that means that you cannot assume that any given instance of `abc` has a `b` attribute, because it depends how it was created. This violates the Liskov substitution principle and will lead to bugs and/or complexity.

Comment: @all, I guess, it was silly of me to post it so fast here, madjaoue's answer is what fixed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you want to init the instance first, then assign `b` inside your class to it.

Here's the idea :

```
class abc:
    def __init__(self, a=0):
        self.a = a
        self.b = None

    @classmethod
    def from_const(cls, b=30):
        instance = cls(10)
        instance.b = b
        return instance

    def printme(self):
        print(self.a,self.b)

a1 = abc(a=100)
a2 = abc.from_const(b=31)
a3 = abc.from_const(b=41)
a4 = abc.from_const(b=51)
a5 = abc.from_const(b=61)
```

Output:

```
(100, None)
(10, 31)
(10, 41)
(10, 51)
(10, 61)
```