# How to understand the different way to pass variable to "@classmethod" constructor

Tags: python, class, constructor, class-method

Here is a Particle class. When I initialize the different particles "byPosition" method, the particles shared the "self.position" variable, anyone have any ideal about why the "self.position" variable is shared?

```py
import random
from PyQt5.QtCore import QPointF
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPen, QColor

class Particle:
    seed = False

    def __init__(self, velocity, position, h, seed):
        self.hue = h

        self.acceleration = QPointF(0, 0)
        self.velocity = velocity
        self.position = position
        self.seed = seed

    @classmethod
    def byXY(cls, x, y, h):
        lowVel = -11 * (y / 480)
        highVel = -5 * (y / 480)
        velocity = QPointF(0, random.uniform(lowVel, highVel))
        position = QPointF(x, y)

        return cls(velocity, position, h, True)

    @classmethod
    def byPosition(cls, position, h):
        mul = random.uniform(6, 9)
        randomVel = [random.uniform(-1, 1) * mul for i in range(2)]
        velocity = QPointF(randomVel[0], randomVel[1])
        position = position

        return cls(velocity, position, h, False)
```

"position" in "byPosition" is passed from "QPointF(0, 0)"
I created two Particle objects "byPosition", and give them random velocities and compute every obeject's position in next frame.

I expected to see two different points' paths.
However, the two objects share the "self.position" data.
Although they have different velocities.

After I edited the "byPosition" method as followed, everything works fine.
I just cannot understand a bit.

```py
    @classmethod
    def byPosition(cls, position, h):
        mul = random.uniform(6, 9)
        randomVel = [random.uniform(-1, 1) * mul for i in range(2)]
        velocity = QPointF(randomVel[0], randomVel[1])
        position = QPointF(position.x(), position.y())

        return cls(velocity, position, h, False)
```

Similar question I found, [@classmethod for constructor overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51541712/classmethod-for-constructor-overloading)

Comment: I suspect that you are assigning something like `pos = QPointF(0, 0)`, then passing that to each invocation of `Particle.byPosition`. Please share the lines of code that invoke that method.

Comment: @brentertainer ```self.firework = Particle.byXY(0, 0, 255) ``` ```for i in range(2): newp = Particle.byPosition(self.firework.position, self.hue) self.particles.append(newp)```.  There is a ```update``` method to move the particle according to the position and velocity. Basic ideal is one particle is moving and then split into two particles with different velocities so that they have different paths.

Comment: `self.firework.position` is a reference to a mutable object. The issue is that you are assigning the same point object. Your change works because it creates a new object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing one list unexpectedly changes another, too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29785084/changing-one-list-unexpectedly-changes-another-too)

Comment: @tao4free Yes, thanks for sharing. You are doing as I expected, and blues's comments elaborating on the problem are correct.

Comment: @blues Thanks for your explanation and duplicate question link. That helps a lot.

Comment: @brentertainer Thanks for kind commenting. I asked a similar question about value pass and reference pass about Java. Now I know they are the same question. Python is somehow easy to use, I never notice that kind of question. Nice.